# Angular Google Maps how to restrict a circle radius?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I work with angular-google-maps and try to restrict a circle radius.
E.g. when radius_changed event fires I check the radius value and if it's less than 100 I assign it 100.

But this technique doesn't work :(

```
events: {
    radius_changed: function (e) {
        if ($scope.circle.radius < 100)
            $scope.circle.radius = 100;
  }
}
```

Here is full jsFiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/q3ggodac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you change existing circle's `radius` attribute, the `angular-google-maps` library won't propagate the change to actual circle object (neither it works the other way).

Luckily, according to the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/circle), the first parameter of the `radius_changed` event handler is the raw `google.maps.Circle` object, which radius you can easily determine using `getRadius()` method and change using `setOptions({radius: N})` function (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), section "Circle Class"). So your code would look like this:

```
events: {
        radius_changed: function (circle_obj) {
            $scope.circle.radius = circle_obj.getRadius(); //you can update the radius scope variable manually
            if ($scope.circle.radius < 100){
                  $scope.circle.radius = 100;
                  circle_obj.setOptions({radius:100});
            }
        }
}
```